# Build a monthly index schedule, considering business days in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Found similar questions that beat around the bush but could not nail down this one.

I want to input an arbitrary date (ex 2022 4 11) and from there build a monthly schedule of dates for "n" months (48 for example) but the series has to:

(a) **take into account business days only and exclude holidays** (I have a list of the holidays).

(b) **add months relative to the first date.** I've found solutions that avoid weekends using offsets like `CustomBusinessDay` but as it avoids weekends in future dates it starts to "drift away" from the original date reference. In my example 2022 4 11 turn into something like 2024 11 05. Because if month 1 is 2022 6 11 it starts from there to add the additional month. I want it to avoid weekends/holidays but still be always the closest possible to a "even" 30-day thing, around day 4 every month in my example. I think +-3 days (sat, sun and a monday of friday holiday) is the kind of move I am looking for, but always going back to the "day 4" reference.

This is a debt payment schedule, hence the caution with that detail.
I need, as much as possible, to keep it close to 30 days otherwise interest calculations further down the code will be all wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way "adding up" a couple of other solutions to similar problems. Code below.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day, BDay
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

    hols = list(pd.to_datetime(pd.read_csv("hols.csv", delimiter=";", > parse_dates=True)['Data']))

    br_bd = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=hols)
    schedule = pd.bdate_range((2019,05,23), periods=48, freq = 'CBM', holidays=hols) + Day(22) - BDay(0)
```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-24', '2019-07-22', '2019-08-22', '2019-09-23',
           '2019-10-22', '2019-11-22', '2019-12-23', '2020-01-21',
           '2020-02-24', '2020-03-23', '2020-04-22', '2020-05-22',
           '2020-06-22', '2020-07-22', '2020-08-24', '2020-09-22',
           '2020-10-22', '2020-11-23', '2020-12-22', '2021-01-21',
           '2021-02-22', '2021-03-22', '2021-04-22', '2021-05-24',
           '2021-06-22', '2021-07-22', '2021-08-23', '2021-09-22',
           '2021-10-22', '2021-11-22', '2021-12-22', '2022-01-21',
           '2022-02-22', '2022-03-21', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-23',
           '2022-06-22', '2022-07-22', '2022-08-22', '2022-09-22',
           '2022-10-24', '2022-11-22', '2022-12-22', '2023-01-23',
           '2023-02-22', '2023-03-22', '2023-04-24', '2023-05-22'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```